# Firebase TypeError: Cannot read property 'Firebase' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am still using the previous version of Firebase which used to work 8.2.3.

In my config file

```
    import firebase from 'firebase'
import { initializeApp, getApp } from "firebase/app";

//setting it up

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  databaseURL: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "x8",
  appId: "xx",
  measurementId: "xxx"
}

const Firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default Firebase
```

Config index to export

```
 import Firebase from "./Firebase";

// as an object
export {Firebase}
```

In my register file

```
import {Firebase} from '../../config';

 Firebase.auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(form.email, form.password)
          .then(userCredential => {
```

It gives me the typeError saying that the firebase is not defined

Comment: Why do you still have `import firebase from 'firebase'` import? Have you tried removing that and then using `firebase` only without uppercase F everywhere else?  Also for auth, you should be using `import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"`. Have you tried following the steps in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";

// Create a Firebase app instance.
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  databaseURL: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "x8",
  appId: "xx",
  measurementId: "xxx"
});

// Get the Firebase object.
const Firebase = firebaseApp;

// ...
```